# Prove $\exp{i\frac{\pi}{2}(-1+\sigma_{i})}=\sigma_{i}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

How do we prove

$e^{{i\frac{\pi}{2}(-1+\sigma_{i})}}=\sigma_{i}$ ?

where $\sigma_{i}:$Pauli matrix and $1=$ Identity matrix

Note: I understand that $i\frac{\pi}{2}(-1+\sigma_{i})$ is anti-hermitian since $(-1+\sigma_{i})$ is hermitian, hence the exponential of it is Unitary.

Comment: The matrix identity is useful for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector. Also note that $e^{i\pi/2(-I + \sigma_i)} = e^{-i\pi/2} e^{i\pi/2\sigma_i}$ since $I$ and $\sigma_i$ commutes.

Comment: @Winther thnx....ohh it was soo easy, i didnt think that way. it was a stupid question.

Comment: It often is easy once you have the right approach, but it's not always easy to see it:) Feel free to answer your own question btw (and you can accept your own question) so that it will have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{\hat{X}+\hat{Y}}=e^{\hat{X}}.e^{\hat{Y}}.e^{-\frac{1}{2}[\hat{X},\hat{Y}]}$ if $[[\hat{X},\hat{Y}],\hat{X}]=0$ and $[[\hat{X},\hat{Y}],\hat{Y}]=0$.

Since $1$ and $\sigma_{i}$ commute, i.e, $i\frac{\pi}{2}[-1,\sigma_{i}]=0$,
$$
e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}(-1+\sigma_{i})}=e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}+i\frac{\pi}{2}\sigma_{i}}=e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}}.e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}\sigma_{i}}
$$

$$
e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}}=cos({\pi}/{2})-isin(\pi/2)=-i
$$

note that $\sigma_{i}^{2}=1$, hence

$$e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}\sigma_{i}}=cos(\pi/2)+i\sigma_{i}.sin(\pi/2)=i.\sigma_{i}$$

Substituting the terms,
$$
e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}(-1+\sigma_{i})}=(-i).(i.\sigma_{i})=\sigma_{i}
$$

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\exp\pars{\ic\,{\pi \over 2}\,\bracks{-1 + \sigma_{k}}} = \sigma_{k}:\ ?}$

Note that 
$\ds{\exp\pars{\ic\,{\pi \over 2}\,\bracks{-1 + \sigma_{k}}} =
-\ic\exp\pars{\ic\,{\pi \over 2}\,\sigma_{k}}}$. Lets consider
$\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{\mu} \equiv \exp\pars{\ic\mu\sigma_{k}}}$. Then,
\begin{align}
\mrm{f}'\pars{\mu} & = \ic\sigma_{k}\,\mrm{f}\pars{\mu}\,,\qquad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{0}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\mathbf{1}\ \pars{~identity~}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\mrm{f}'\pars{0}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\ic\sigma_{k}}
\end{array}\right.
\\[5mm]
\mrm{f}''\pars{\mu} & = \ic\sigma_{k}\,\mrm{f}'\pars{\mu} = -\,\mrm{f}\pars{\mu}
\quad\implies\quad\mrm{f}''\pars{\mu} + \mrm{f}\pars{\mu} = 0
\end{align}

---

Then,
\begin{align}
\mrm{f}\pars{\mu} & = A\sin\pars{\mu} + B\cos\pars{\mu}\quad\implies\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcrcl}
\ds{0\,A}& \ds{+} &\ds{B} & \ds{=} & \ds{\mathbf{1}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{A}& \ds{+} &\ds{0\,B} & \ds{=} & \ds{\ic\sigma_{k}}
\end{array}\right.
\\[5mm]
\implies\,\mrm{f}\pars{\mu} & = \ic\sigma_{k}\sin\pars{\mu} + \mathbf{1}\cos\pars{\mu}
\implies
\color{#f00}{\exp\pars{\ic\,{\pi \over 2}\,\bracks{-1 + \sigma_{k}}}} =
-\ic\,\mrm{f}\pars{\pi \over 2} = -\ic\pars{\ic\sigma_{k}} = \color{#f00}{\sigma_{k}}
\end{align}